# Akka test for deadletters

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

How can I make assertion against deadletters in Akka while testing? 
I have an actor which can switch behaviours (using `become`) and deals with some Futures dispatched using separate Dispatcher. In some certain condition it should simply reject other messages. 
Those correctly go to a deadletters, however I would like to try to assert for them (or lack of). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dead letters are delivered using the event stream so you can subscribe to that in your tests with a probe and verify messages or lack of messages

```
system.eventStream.subscribe(probe, classOf[DeadLetter])
```

Comment: easy and it works. Moreover, the same can be used for `UnhandledMessage` class instead of `DeadLetter`. Thanks!